# How to have systemd-resolved correctly come alive after hot plug?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, systemd, resolv.conf

**Setup**

I am playing with a small embedded board running Debian Jessie. I am using as much `systemd` stuff as I can, including the networking stuff. I have added the file:

`/etc/systemd/network/eth0-dhcp.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

I fix the `/etc/resolv.conf` file to be a symlink `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`.

The version reported by systemd is 215.

I have the board plugged into my MacBookPro which is sharing it's wifi connection as ethernet.

**What Happens**

1) At first boot, everything is fine. `ifconfig` shows that I have a valid ip address handed out by the macbook. I can `ping 0.debian.pool.ntp.org` and get valid responses. `cat /etc/resolv.conf` shows a valid `nameserver` address. This is all as expected and a Good Thing (tm)

2) If I disconnect the ethernet cable, I get a set of messages on the console indicating the link is down. At this point, `ifconfig` no longer shows an ip address. `cat /etc/resolv.conf` is now empty. And of course ping doesn't work anymore either. This is also all as expected.

3) I reconnect the cable. Now I get a set of messages indicating the link is up. At this point, `ifconfig` indicates I once again have a valid ip address. But `/etc/resolv.conf` doesn't have anything in it. So my ping command doesn't work, no address. However I can `ping 204.2.134.162` (The earlier reported address of said host). So I would conclude that while my networking layer correctly came back alive with the hot plug of the cable, `systemd-resolved` did not?

After doing a `systemctl restart systems-resolved`, `/etc/resolv.conf` shows an entry again, but the ip addresses resolved are now different and still don't ping.

Can someone explain to my what is happening here? What does it take to get the name resolution working again after a network hot plug event? Feel free to be pedantic, most of my networking knowledge is anecdotal and trial-and-error learned by seat of pants.

**UPDATE**

It has been pointed out that the debian pool addresses may indeed be different and unpingable. Using `google.com` instead, that part always works fine. so the remaining question is then

*How do get systemd-resolved to restart after the network is hot plugged?*